# How to set Socket Connection Timeout for a ZeroMQ Socket in python?

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to check if a socket is available to be connected to. If the socket is not open, I expect some return value. How do I do ? I found something on ZMQ_CONNECT_TIMEOUT for C++ bindings. I couldn't find it for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"How do I do ?"*

```
>>> import zmq
>>> zmq.CONNECT_TIMEOUT
79
...
>>> aReturnCODE = aZeroMQ_SocketINSTANCE.setsockopt( zmq.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
...                                                  aTimeoutVALUE_ms
...                                                  )
>>> print( aReturnCODE )
```